# Use Theme.of(context) to change visuals in the first frame of flutter

Tags: flutter

I need use Theme.of(context) at run time due to reasons, I want the change to happen when the application is drawn/rendered/mounted for the first time. So i want to use something like useLayoutEffect(() => {}, []) in react.

initState gives me the context but I cant use `Theme.of(context)` on it which I assume is because i dont have access to `context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` yet. Correct me if I am wrong but I assume since you inherit Theme from the last parent to define a theme, therefore it comes under the category of `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType`.

I looked into `addPostFrameCallback` but it still renders 1 frame before calling my method.
So the order is, initState -> didChangeDependancies -> Build (1 frame) -> postFrameCallback effects.

So i wrote my code like this,

```
late Color x;
var firstRender = true;
late BuildContext myContext;

void initState() {
   super()
   SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        setState(() {
          firstRender = false;
        });
        print(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryColor;
   }
   
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
       if (firstRender){
            return Container();
       }
       return MyFullWidget;
   }
}
```

This works but i wanted to check if its an anti pattern? is there a better way to do this, is there anything like addPreFrameCallback?

Comment: So read the `Theme.of(context)` in `didChangeDependancies` method. What's the problem?

Comment: Because that can get fired multiple times, whenever the dependencies change aye?. But I know for a fact that my callback only needs to be fired once (well as long as my theme doesn't change but I am not changing the theme)

Comment: If there is a solution where U can use didChangeDep but, it only fires when certain dependencies are changed , like Theme , then that would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the task is still not clear but why don't you do like that?

```dart
bool _wasCallbackThatNeedToBeFiredOnceCalled = false;

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  if(!_wasCallbackThatNeedToBeFiredOnceCalled) {
    _callbackThatNeedToBeFiredOnce();
    _wasCallbackThatNeedToBeFiredOnceCalled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: ye this is another approach, a much better approach than mine. But even in this didChangeDependencies will fire on every dependency change and then you run that if statement. I wanted to see if its possible to fire it on ONLY one dependency change. For example, how in react you can specify the dependencies in a dependancy array. Just because it looks cleaner. But yes this does look a lot cleaner than returning an empty container in build. Thank you.
Just out of curiosity, is there no way to have a callback in preFrameCallback.

Comment: There is no such method. This is Flutter not React. :) It uses another approach. What is the reason of your question?

Comment: haha fair enough. So what I was trying to achieve is, change the background colour of different buttons on ToggleButton. If the first button is selected, then I want it to have primaryColor but if the second button is selected, I want it to have tertiaryColor. So I made an object that stores the `theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryColor` and `secondaryColor`, and then inside `onPressed`, I change the fillColor. While I can use theme.of(context) inside onPressed itself, because build has the full context. Just out of pure curiosity I wanted to see if its possible to use context outside build

Comment: Is this sample suitable for you: https://gist.github.com/bambinoua/be4f234aabd983d4abf17406e43be56f?

Comment: Yes it is, thank you. Hadnt seen `ValueListenableBuilder` before. So I had to understand that first. Thank you